# How to handle routing in a DukeScript web application

Tags: dukescript

DukeScript looks like a life saver for we Java guys! I am considering it for a serious project. Was curious to know whether it's production ready and well documented. Also, liked to know what would be the best way to support routing in a web application.

I asked this question at the [official google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dukescript/K14YFPtgKWM), but didn't get a reply. So, thought to re-ask here.

Comment: The DS community is still very small, you will get a reply. Perhaps you should reformulate this question as one question. Production ready is very generic. Routing in web application, I believe it does, it's a client-client architecture, were would web requests directed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a blog post with a little example](https://dukescript.com/best/practices/2015/08/16/Simple-Routing-with-DukeScript.html). It shows a simple integration of location hash based routing with knockout templates. The full example code is [available on github](https://github.com/dukescript/dukescript-routing-demo).

You might also use one of the javascript libraries like sammy or pagerjs, which would require integration with these frameworks, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.